# Split string with | separator in java

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string that's like this: `1|"value"|;`

I want to split that string and have chosen `|` as the separator.

My code looks like this:

```
String[] separated = line.split("|");
```

What I get is an array that contains all characters as one entry:

```
separated[0] = ""
separated[1] = "1"
separated[2] = "|"
separated[3] = """
separated[4] = "v"
separated[5] = "a"
...
```

Does anyone know why?
Can't I split an string with `|`?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`|` is treated as an `OR` in RegEx. So you need to escape it:

```
String[] separated = line.split("\\|");
```

Comment: If your separator is dynamic, `line.split("\\" + separator)` won't work with `;` or `,`. Another solution would be `line.split("[" + separator + "]")`, because characters in brackets are escaped as well.

Comment: @JannikArndt that's a good point and a neat trick, but I think Pattern.quote is better.

Answer (score 10):

You have to escape the `|` because it has a special meaning in a regex. Have a look at the [`split(..)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
String[] sep = line.split("\\|");
```

The second `\` is used to escape the `|` and the first `\` is used to escape the second `\` :).

Comment: Why is it that you don't need a third \ to escape the second \ and so on indefinitely?

Answer (score 5):

The parameter to `split` method is a regex, as you can read [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). Since `|` has a special meaning in regular expressions, you need to escape it. The code then looks like this (as others have shown already):

```
String[] separated = line.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 5):

It won't work this way, because you have to escape the Pipe | first.
The following sample code, found at (http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0438.html) shows an example.

```
public class StringSplit {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    String testString = "Real|How|To";
    // bad
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        testString.split("|")
    ));
    // output : [, R, e, a, l, |, H, o, w, |, T, o]

    // good
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
      testString.split("\\|")
    ));
    // output : [Real, How, To]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Escape the pipe. It works.

```
String.split("\\|");
```

The pipe is a special character in regex meaning OR

Answer (score 3):

Try this: `String[] separated = line.split("\\|");`

My answer is better. I corrected the spelling of "separated" :)

Also, the reason this works? `|` means "OR" in regex. You need to escape it.

Answer (score 2):

String.split() uses regex, so you need to escape the '|' like .split("\\|");

Answer (score 2):

you can replace the pipe with another character like '#' before spliting, try this

```
String[] seperated = line.replace('|','#').split("#");
```

Answer (score 0):

| means OR in regex, you should escape it. What's more, a single '\', you get '\|' means nothing in Java string. So you should also escape the '\' itself, which yields '\|'.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StringUtil {

  private static final String HT = "\t";
  private static final String CRLF = "\r\n";

  // This class cannot be instantiated
  private StringUtil() {
  }

  /**
   * Split the string into an array of strings using one of the separator in
   * 'sep'.
   * 
   * @param s
   *            the string to tokenize
   * @param sep
   *            a list of separator to use
   * 
   * @return the array of tokens (an array of size 1 with the original string
   *         if no separator found)
   */
  public static String[] split(final String s, final String sep) {
    // convert a String s to an Array, the elements
    // are delimited by sep
    final Vector<Integer> tokenIndex = new Vector<Integer>(10);
    final int len = s.length();
    int i;

    // Find all characters in string matching one of the separators in 'sep'
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
      if (sep.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) != -1)
        tokenIndex.addElement(new Integer(i));

    final int size = tokenIndex.size();
    final String[] elements = new String[size + 1];

    // No separators: return the string as the first element
    if (size == 0)
      elements[0] = s;
    else {
      // Init indexes
      int start = 0;
      int end = (tokenIndex.elementAt(0)).intValue();
      // Get the first token
      elements[0] = s.substring(start, end);

      // Get the mid tokens
      for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        // update indexes
        start = (tokenIndex.elementAt(i - 1)).intValue() + 1;
        end = (tokenIndex.elementAt(i)).intValue();
        elements[i] = s.substring(start, end);
      }
      // Get last token
      start = (tokenIndex.elementAt(i - 1)).intValue() + 1;
      elements[i] = (start < s.length()) ? s.substring(start) : "";
    }

    return elements;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern.compile("|").splitAsStream(String you want to split).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic method you can use for this purpose. It will handle any delimiter.
**Pattern.quote** does the magic.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public static String[] split(String strToSplit, String delimiter) {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(strToSplit)) {
        return new String[] {};
    } else if (StringUtils.isBlank(delimiter)) {
        return new String[] { strToSplit };
    }

    return strToSplit.split(Pattern.quote(delimiter));
}
```

In your example:

```
String[] separated = split(line, "|");
```

Comment: I don't like your method because it does more than was asked for and as a result has more dependencies, but I very much like your mention of Pattern.quote, a method which needs more publicity!

Comment: I used StringUtils just for convenience, but it can be easily removed by testing nullability and emptyness in the old fashion way...