# Java String.split mehod don't work well

Tags: java, string, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split string with | separator in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305675/split-string-with-separator-in-java)

I'm little confused as when i do the following:

```
String example1 = "Hello|World";
String[] splitRes;

splitRes = example1.split("|");
```

I don't get split string
 Hello    index 0
 World    index 1

But if I'll do

```
 String example1 = "Hello:World";  
 String[] splitRes;

 splitRes = example1.split(":");
```

then it works..
Why is it happening?

Comment: Maybe it's worth reading [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))? Quote: *"Splits this string around matches of the given [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)."*

Answer (score 6):

split uses a regex, you must escape the pipe because it is a "or" operator in regex:

```
example1.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 2):

`String.split()` expects regular expression as argument, `|` is a meta character "OR" in regular expression. You have to escape with \ (so it becomes `\|`). Note that in Java string, you have to write it as \\ since \ is also an escape character in Java string.

Answer (score 1):

| is used  in regular expression, `.split` also use  regular expression  so you need to escape it.

```
String str = ""Hello:World"; ";
String[] temp;
String delimiter = "\\|";
SepString= str.split(delimiter);
  /* print test */
for(int i =0; i < SepString.length ; i++)
System.out.println(SepString[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split takes a regexp as an argument, | is a a regexp symbol.
You would have to escape it using `\` which in a java string is two of them: `\\`

```
.split("\\|");
```