# split regular expression string by main "or" operators

Tags: java, regex

I just wanted to ask if there is an easy way to do this, before I start building a fully fletched regex interpreter or at least a quite big state machine, just to figure out what degree the or operators have and where to split. To make things clearer let's put a random example here:

```java
String regex = "test (1|2|3)|testing\\||tester\\nNextLine[ab|]|(test)";
```

The result I want is the following, spliting the regex by its main `or` operators:

```java
String[] result = { "test (1|2|3)", "testing\\|", "tester\\nNextLine[ab|]", "(test)" };
```

As mentioned I already have some ideas on complex solutions that involve going through the string char by char, skipping escaped characters, figuring out where all the brackets open and close, on what bracket-level that character is, adding the indices of those level 0 '|' characters to a list and splitting the string by those indices, but I am searching for a simple one- or two-liner

aka a more beautiful solution. Is there one?

---

To clarify this even further - I want all alternatives like this in one string array

[image]

---

UPDATE: Not the most beautiful version, but I actually implemented something like a state machine for this now:

```java
private ArrayList<String> parseFilters(String regex) {
    ArrayList<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();
    Stack<Integer> brackets = new Stack<>();
    int level = 0;
    int bracketType = -1;
    char lastChar = ' ';
    char currentChar = ' ';
    for (int i = 0; i < regex.length(); i++) {
        currentChar = regex.charAt(i);
        if (lastChar == '\\' || "^$?*+".indexOf(currentChar) >= 0)
            ;
        else if (level == 0 && "|".indexOf(currentChar) >= 0)
            indices.add(i + 1);
        else if ((bracketType = "([{".indexOf(currentChar)) >= 0) {
            brackets.push(bracketType);
            level++;
        } else if ((bracketType = ")]}".indexOf(currentChar)) >= 0) {
            if (bracketType == brackets.peek()) {
                brackets.pop();
                level--;
            }
        }
        lastChar = currentChar;
    }
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    int lastIndex = 0;
    for (int i : indices)
        results.add(regex.substring(lastIndex, (lastIndex = i) - 1));
    results.add(regex.substring(lastIndex));
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Please see this post for escaping the `|` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305675/split-string-with-separator-in-java

Comment: um, yes I already stumbled apon this in my search for answers... but what does that have to do with my question? Spliting my regex string by "\\|" does not help me at all, as I only want to split if it is a main one at base level.

Comment: You just need to double it and split on `"\\|\\|"` which will become `||` when it's been parsed twice.

Comment: Not what I originally wanted but I'll keep it in mind... Only problem here are statements like `testing\\|||test`, `testing(\\|||\\|)||test` or `testing(\\||\\|)||test` and I'm right back at the beginning as the regex is a user input. The question 'how do i split by first level expressions'.

Comment: If your input data can contain nested structures like `a(b|c(d|e))|f` than regex may not be best choice in Java, since it doesn't support recursion (unless you want to write regex like http://www.drregex.com/2017/11/match-nested-brackets-with-regex-new.html but that would become maintenance hell very quickly).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof of concept Java program splitting on double `||` and leaving single `|` untouched.
This would be more complicated to achieve with regex.
We have to double escape each pipe because the pattern is parsed twice, once when it is loaded into the variable and again when it is used as a pattern. `\\|\\|` is thus reduced to `||`.

```
class split{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String lineTest = "test (1|2|3)|testing\\||tester\\nNextLine[ab||]|(test)";
    String separated[] = 
    lineTest.split("\\|\\|");
    for ( int i = 0; i < separated.length;i++){
      System.out.println( separated[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
test (1|2|3)|testing\
tester\nNextLine[ab
]|(test)
```